# Starting service says me that permission is denied

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian

RUN useradd bar && usermod -aG sudo bar
RUN echo bar:12345 | chpasswd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get install -y mariadb-server && apt-get install -y php php-mbstring
RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

USER bar
WORKDIR /serv

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

When I'm trying to start container (created using docker run or docker-compose), I'm getting "Permission denied", and I guess why - I need to type password to activate this service, but how can I do it when container is starting, if I don't use bash in this moment? Is there some another way?

Comment: What's the exact error?  How are you starting the container?  (Generally you need neither user passwords nor `sudo` in Docker and deleting these will simplify your setup, but probably won't fix the underlying issue.)

Comment: `docker run -it server bash` - like this, then I start service inside, if I use docker-compose, it outputs `Permission denied: AH00091: apache2: could not open error log file /var/log/apache2/error.log` - /var/log can't be accessed without root's rights, that's why I need password

Comment: One option is to launch Apache as root, then use its [`User`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#user) directive to drop privileges.  Another is to fix the log directory's permissions.  Anyone who has the image can look at its `docker history` and trivially discover this password; when you `docker run` the container you can specify an arbitrary user ID at that point, and you never need user passwords or `sudo`.